# UIAlertView in ARC app

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I have iphone sample application with one button. On tap it calls code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"test"
                          message:@"test"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Application has ARC enabled.

The problem is that if I click on OK button in alert, application crashes with EXC_BAD_ADDRESS - probably because of alert is already removed by arc.

What is recommended way to solve this? without adding property to viewcontroller

thanks

Comment: Use the zombies instrument to find out where the crash is occurring.

Comment: What are you actually doing in the delegate method, and where, exactly, is the crash?

Answer (score 5):

My guess is either you haven't implemented the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) methods or that self has gone out of scope.

If you don't care about being alerted when someone dismisses the alert box, change the delegate to nil.
e.g.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"test"
                          message:@"test"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 5):

The delegate property of UIAlertView is declared as a weak reference (indicated by the assign keyword).  This means ARC will not increment the retain count and you will need to retain a reference to the delegate object (whether it is self or a separate object).  This reference should be maintained for the full life of the UIAlertView.

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;    // weak reference
```

I assume that the reason for this is to prevent a loop and failure to release as in the common case the object creating the UIAlertView will retain a reference to it and be it's delegate so closing the loop and preventing release.

This is probably a common pattern for delegates but I hadn't realised until I hit exactly the same issue.  I ran in the simulator with zombie detection enabled and it clearly indicated the reference counts and I saw that it was not being retained by the UIAlertView.  That was when I checked the header file.

The answer to this question provides some additional information about delegates on system classes and the assign keyword.
[iPhone ARC Release Notes - dealloc on system classes delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934615/iphone-arc-release-notes-dealloc-on-system-classes-delegates?rq=1)